# CSS Cards: How to set the same height of the image without knowing its height

Tags: html, css, gallery, text-alignment

This is my goal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnALf.png
The images are well aligned. Despite the different heights of the images and the text, each beginning of a section is aligned with the one next to it as you can see in the image.

How can I make that with CSS?

*P.S*:

- I can use tables to achieve this easily! But I will need to create other elements with the same images and texts for the responsive version and I do not want to do that.
- I can use Javascript to give the image container a minimum height equal to the tallest height of the three images but I feel like it can be done using CSS => much easier for the responsive version. Plus this trick will not work for the "title" part because on smaller screen sizes, it will just break (for both the "px" and the "vw" units)

```js
/*window.onload = function(){
let imgs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.imgContainer img'));
let oldMinHeight = 0;
imgs.forEach(function(singleImg){
        if(singleImg.clientHeight > oldMinHeight){
                oldMinHeight = singleImg.clientHeight;
        }
});                                                                    
     Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.imgContainer')).forEach(function(singleImgContainer){
        singleImgContainer.style.minHeight = (oldMinHeight) + 'px';
});
}*/

//This is the script that gives the minHeight to the image containers.
```

```css
        *{
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        section{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .product{
            margin: 0 2vw;
            padding-top: 2vw;
            background:#ececec;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        .product .imgContainer{
            display: flex;
            width:15vw;
            height: auto;
            margin:auto;
        }
        .product img{
            margin:auto;
            width:100%;
            display: block;
        }
        .product .desc, .product .title{
            width:15vw;
            margin-left: 2vw;
            margin-right: 2vw;
            margin-bottom: 2vw;
        }
```

```html
<section>
        <div class="product">
            <div class="imgContainer"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/12641780/pexels-photo-12641780.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-stayhereforu-12641780.jpg&fm=jpg">           </div>
            <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
            <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="product">
            <div class="imgContainer"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/12681236/pexels-photo-12681236.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-vildan-hanne-do%C4%9Fan-12681236.jpg&fm=jpg"></div>
            <div class="title">Title</div>
            <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="product">
            <div class="imgContainer"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/12489081/pexels-photo-12489081.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-josh-hild-12489081.jpg&fm=jpg"></div>
            <div class="title">Title</div>
            <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @gerard Thank you for your response. But I cannot specify height because what if different photos with different heights are uploaded, I don't want my client to keep changing the CSS when changing images that's why. It is a solution to do it "manually." Is there a CSS trick or sth that gives more of an automatic solution? It happens despite the image heights. Just takes the bigger height, give it to all image containers, and done.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the property [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) for the image and set a fixed height for its container.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.product {
  margin: 0 2vw;
  padding-top: 2vw;
  background: #ececec;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.product .imgContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 150px; /* Changed */
  margin: auto;
}

.product img {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain; /* Added */
}

.product .desc,
.product .title {
  width: 15vw;
  margin-left: 2vw;
  margin-right: 2vw;
  margin-bottom: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="imgContainer"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/12641780/pexels-photo-12641780.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-stayhereforu-12641780.jpg&fm=jpg"> </div>
    <div class="title">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title</div>
    <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="imgContainer"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/12681236/pexels-photo-12681236.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-vildan-hanne-do%C4%9Fan-12681236.jpg&fm=jpg"></div>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="imgContainer"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/12489081/pexels-photo-12489081.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-josh-hild-12489081.jpg&fm=jpg"></div>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</div>
  </div>
</section>
```